# Django: QuerySet with ExpressionWrapper

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I currently try to get `max_total_gross`from all tickets
within an event. That's how far I came but it doesn't work yet.

```
tickets = event.tickets.all().annotate(
    max_total_gross=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('quantity') * F('price_gross'),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).values(
    'max_total_gross'
)
```

**Goal:**

```
Sum(
    price_gross_x_quantity_ticket_1 +
    price_gross_x_quantity_ticket_2 +
    price_gross_x_quantity_ticket_3 +
    [...]
)
```

**Here my ticket model:**

```
class Ticket(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        'events.Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tickets'
    )  # CASCADE = delete the ticket if the event is deleted
    price_gross = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Price gross"), help_text=_("Includes tax if you set any.")
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Quantity"),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100_000)],
    )
    # [...]
```

Comment: So you want the sum of *all* your `Ticket` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [**`.annotate(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) means you add an attribute to every `Ticket` object. What you here want is probably want is [**`.aggregate(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
max_total_gross = event.tickets.aggregate(
    max_total_gross=Sum(
        F('quantity') * F('price_gross')
    )
)['max_total_gross']
```

Or if you want to calculate this *per* `Event`, you can use:

```
Event.objects.annotate(
    max_total_gross=Sum(
        F('tickets__quantity') * F('tickets__price_gross')
    )
)
```

Now each `Event` that arises from this queryset will have an attribute `max_total_gross` that contains the sum of the quantity of the related tickets times its price gross.

Comment: I chose the first option now as it seems to be the shortest one from all the suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

max_val_dict = event.tickets.all().annotate(
    max_total_gross=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('quantity') * F('price_gross'),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).aggregate(total=Sum(
    'max_total_gross'
  )
)

value = max_val_dict.get('total')
```

Comment: One question: Is it on purpose there is `Sum` twice?

Comment: yep, but it will work. But @Willem Van Onsem's answer is much better and has proper explanation

Comment: Okay :) Thank you!